# Does Chrome's Developer Tools have an option to disable cache as firebug does?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Does Chrome's Developer Tools have an option to disable cache as firebug does?
If so would someone be so kind as to point me towards it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [Issue 8742](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8742) in the Chromium issue tracker a comment has been added just some hours ago:

*There is now a checkbox for disabling cache in settings.*

So there is hope that the feature to disable cache will finally make its way into Chrome. In the meantime, I put into my development server's Apache config:

```
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
```

Guess that should do the trick.

**Update**: In Chrome 15's Developer Tools settings (cogwheel in lower right hand corner) there is an option *Network / Disable cache*. Also you can clear the cache easily by right clicking in the network tab and selecting *Clear browser cache*.

Comment: Dev Tools settings are plentiful and useful! Don't forget to memorise the keyboard shortcuts :)